# TextView change text first click doesn't work

Tags: android, textview

[image]

This `TextView` has two functions. Firstly, it can switch the password between two status, HIDE and SHOW. Then it change the `TextView` text between "SHOW" and "HIDE".
The first function can work perfectly. But the second didn't work very well. Whenever I open my app. The first click on the `TextView`, It only change the password status, but not the `TextView` text. Unless I click multiple times, both function would be work.
After several test, I found only the `TextView` text can not work when I clicked the widget at the very first time. I am a noob on Android Studio, so I think this might be just a simple question. Are there anyone can tell me why this happened, please! Thank you!

```
   TVtoggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (TVtoggle.getText() == "SHOW") {
             ETpassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
                ETpassword.setSelection(ETpassword.length());
                TVtoggle.setText("HIDE");
            }
            else {
                TVtoggle.setText("SHOW");

                ETpassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | 
                InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                ETpassword.setSelection(ETpassword.length());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Use this `if (TVtoggle.getText().toString().equals("SHOW") )`

Comment: @NileshRathod I think its not duplicate as he has different problem but solution is just comparing string.

Comment: Thank you Nilesh Rathod! You solved my problem.Love You!